# crontab: which one is the right job definition?

Tags: linux, cron

Which one is the right definition for a `crontab` job?
With or without the `user` before the execution path?

```
 .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
 |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
 |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
 |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
 |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
 |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  * <user>  <command>
```

On Debian, `crontab -l` show a backup example as:

```
....
For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
at 5 a.m every week with:
0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
...
```

There is no `user` here!!
The `/etc/crontab` content (on the same box), gives a different clue:

```
....
and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
that none of the other crontabs do.
...
```

Comment: Per-user crontabs don't have a user name, since the user is always the owner of the file. The global `/etc/crontab` file has an extra username field.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Questions about Unix belong on unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `crontab` does *not* * allow for specifying a user to run as...

... unless you're in the root crontab.

If you check my [favorite linux admin reference](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference), you'll not near the bottom that there are some tricks to running certain chrontab entries as a particular user. However, the best practice, if you wish to do so, would be to edit the crontab of the user:

```
crontab -u <username> -e
```

#### If you must...

```
0 0 * * * sudo -u [user] [command]
```

But this can only be done in the crontab of a user with sudo permissions, and as [fcm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4449516/fcm) pointed out, such a user could just edit the root crontab.

#### Most flavors of 'NIX require a user in the root crontab `/etc/crontab`

```
0 0 * * * [user] [command]
```

## Conclusion

If you want to specify which user is running a specific cron job, the best practice is to do one of the following, depending on the use-case:

1. **root crontab**

   - /etc/crontab
   - `sudo crontab`
   - `<time> <user> <command>`
2. **user crontab**

   - `crontab -u <username> -e`
   - `<time> <command>`

Comment: This need to be interpreted as: if defined on the root crontab you must specify the 'user', for a $USER crontab the user can't be present. About sudo: if you belong to the sudo group, why not to use the root crontab to start with... btw: /var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER are temporary files, may not preserve during reboot. Files on /etc/cron.d/ are also considered 'root'.

Comment: Why you write 'You may be able to specify the user as you described, but only in the root crontab.': it's either 'must' or 'must not'; I can't compile the verb 'may' in my limited computer language.

Comment: @fcm, don't forget that linux can be heavily customized, and some distros will behave differently. That's why ***may*** should be in your vocabulary unless you're talking about a specific distro.